# How can I test if a socket connection is open?

Tags: java, html, sockets, tcp, httprequest

I am trying to test a socket connection before sending requests to a server.  I know that with TCP protocol, sockets do not provide a live connection.  So, to test it, I have to send/receive data from the socket.

I am sending the following header:

```
 HEAD * HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: *****
```

It is successful, and I get the following response:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Server: *****
 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: 0
 Connection: keep-alive
```

However, when I do this again with the same header, the input stream is closed and I get an error, meaning I can't receive any data.

I am working in Java, but I don't think there lies the problem.

Is there a request I can send to the server, without it having terminated the connection.

Note, I can send valid requests fine, but they are too long to use as a test mechanism.  I need to test it, because there is a limit on the number of connections allowed, and I need to make sure that someone else isn't using the connection at the same time.

Comment: How do you know that nothing changes between your ping an your request? E.g., you do your ping, all is fine, then you do your request and in the meantime someone is "using the connection at the same time" (whatever that means).

Comment: When you create a socket, a connection is not live (i.e. it is not really connected).  The sockets are not communicating.  This means that you can create 1000 connections to a server, where only 100 are allowed.  But, if I start using those connections with requests, 900 will throw an error.  I need to test it so that I am unable to create the other 900 in the first place.

Comment: Take a valid GET request that works. Change GET to HEAD.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I tried, and while it works, the connection is terminated after one response.  I think that the server takes POST requests, so I will try that.

Comment: Update:  I was able to find a workaround that accomplishes my main goal, but if anyone can think of a way to "test" a socket connection in general, please let us know.